# Remove Firebase child based on spinner selection in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, spinner

I'm new to Android Studio so this may be easy for some of you.

I have a spinner that reads Names of Visitors from Firebase Database.

Once the Name is chosen and a button is clicked I want that child to be removed from the Database.

This is my code for Spinner in onCreate:

```
databaseVisitors = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
databaseVisitors.child("visitorsToCO").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot datasnapshot) {
        final List<String> visitorsToCO = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (DataSnapshot areaSnapshot: datasnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String visitorName = areaSnapshot.child("visitorName").getValue(String.class);
            if (visitorName!=null){
                visitorsToCO.add(visitorName);
            }
        }

        Spinner spinnerV = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.visitorName);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CheckOutActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, visitorsToCO);
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerV.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }
```

And this is my code for the button:

```
btnCheckOut2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addVisitorCheckOut();
            deleteVisitorToCO();
            openMainActivity();
        }
    });

public void deleteVisitorToCO()
{
    databaseVisitors = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("visitorsToCO");

    final String name = visitorName.getSelectedItem().toString();

    Query query = databaseVisitors.child("visitorsToCO").orderByChild("visitorName").equalTo(name);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot itemSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                itemSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

[image: This is my Firebase Database]

Comment: What is the child node's Key-Pair Value?

Comment: Please add the code that you are using so far and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: Sorry, thought that the next step will ask me to provide code @AlexMamo

Comment: If you are hardcoding the name `databaseVisitors.child("visitorsToCO").orderByChild("visitorName").equalTo("Joe");`, does it work?

Comment: That  also did work but what got the whole thing working the way I needed is the answer below. Thanks anyway @AlexMamo also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
databaseVisitors = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
databaseVisitors.child("visitorsToCO").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot datasnapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot areaSnapshot: datasnapshot.getChildren()) {
            if(areaSnapshot.child(visitorName).getValue().toString().equals(spinnerV.getSelectedItem().toString()))
            {
                areaSnapShot.setValue(null);
            }

        }


    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that, just a small change was needed by changing areaSnapShot.setValue(null); to areaSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();. Greatly appreciated, thanks again